# problem while parsing the CDATA

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser, cdata

```
   <text><![CDATA[øCu·l es tu principal reto, objetivo o problema?]]></text>
```

while parsing the above tag, its crashing.
how to parse the CDATA

the same line is appearing in windows like this...

```
<text><![CDATA[¿Cuál es tu principal reto, objetivo o problema?]]></text>
```

due to the special chars the parser is crashing.

why they are converted into special chars in Mac..?
how to solve this?

Comment: .. an "its an error" will not help without knowing what error it is

Comment: You need to post details of the crash. You're probably doing something wrong in the CDATA delegate callback.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, the string as you post it here looks like something has gone wrong with the encoding. "ø" is not a Spanish character.

What xml parser are you using? I would guess that somewhere in that string is a character, possibly hidden, or maybe it's "ø" which makes your parser crash.

**Edit** (in response to the OP's comment)

I will try to guess what is happening and hope you can use my guess to resolve what is actually happening. So when you created the xml file you used some editor. This editor used a particular encoding. This means that it transferred the characters on your screen into bytes on your disk using a particular mapping from character into bytes (it encoded the characters into bytes). There are many different encodings, one common encoding is called Latin-1. So let's assume the file was encoded using Latin-1. After creating it, you transferred the file onto another machine where you opened it in a different editor. Now, how does the new editor know the encoding of the file? The answer is that it probably tried to guess the encoding. Now here is where the problem arises: it guessed wrong and interpreted the bytes using an encoding other than Latin-1.

While you have your (garbled) file open in an editor try selecting different encodings from the menu. The one that displays all your special characters correctly is likely to be the one used when the file was created.

**Edit 2**
But my other question remains: what xml parser are you using?

**Edit 3**

Ok, so now when you write "crashing", do you actually mean crashing or does it just return? Do you get an error message? If yes, what? Can you do the following:

Remove the funny characters from this line and run your code on the following:

```
<text><![CDATA[l es tu principal reto, objetivo o problema?]]></text>
```

Does it still crash?

Comment: Yes Matt u r right. thats not a spanish word. the actual sentence i posted. but that good in windows. but the same line is changing to the first line in Mac. why it is so?

Comment: @Rakesh: my answer is too long for a comment, so I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: im using the NSXMLParser.    im converting the csv files in to xml files using a php code. i get the csv file from client. TextEdit and Xcode is also showing the currupted data.

Comment: @Rakesh: Here is another thread about a problem with NSXmlParser: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=493022